# Convergence of limit with integer part of $x$: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2\left(\Bigr[\frac1x\Bigr]+\Bigr[\frac2{x}\Bigr]+\dots+\Bigr[\frac{k}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Good day!
I tried to solve this problem;the process is correct?

The problem si:

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. With $[x]$ denote the integer part of $ x $.
Calculate

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \Biggr(x^2 (\Bigr[\frac{1}{x}\Bigr]+\Bigr[\frac{2}{x}\Bigr]+\dots + \Bigr[\frac{k}{x}\Bigr])\Biggr),\qquad k\in \mathbb{N}.$$

My solution:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \Biggr(x^2 (\Bigr[\frac{1}{x}\Bigr]+\Bigr[\frac{2}{x}\Bigr]+\dots + \Bigr[\frac{k}{x}\Bigr])\Biggr)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ x^2\Biggr(\frac{1}{[x]}+\frac{2}{[x]}+\dots + \frac{k}{[x]}\Biggr)=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ x^2\Biggr(\frac{1+2+3+\dots+k}{[x]}\Biggr)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ x^2 \ \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{j}{[x]}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^2 }{[x]} \ \sum_{j=1}^{k} \ {j}$$

Now we know that:
$$x-1<[x]\le x.$$
so
$$ \frac{1}{x}\le\frac{1 }{[x]}\le\frac{1}{x-1}$$
because ${x\to 0^+}$.
So
$$ \frac{x^2}{x}\le\frac{x^2 }{[x]}\le\frac{x^2}{x-1}$$
passing to the limit, and applying the comparison, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^2 }{[x]} \ \sum_{j=1}^{k} \ {j}=0$$

Comment: $[x]=0$ if $0\le x<1$; so, your first step is not valid. But you can replace $[1/x]$ with just $1/x$ at the expense of introducing an inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works with the correction I noted in the comments:

Since $[y]\le y$ for $y\ge0$,
$$
\eqalign{0&\le
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \Biggr(x^2 (\Bigr[\frac{1}{x}\Bigr]+\Bigr[\frac{2}{x}\Bigr]+\dots + \Bigr[\frac{k}{x}\Bigr])\Biggr)\cr
&\le
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \Biggr(x^2 ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x} +\dots +  \frac{k}{x} )\Biggr)\cr
&=
\lim_{x\to 0^+} [ x  (1+2+3+\cdots+ k)]\cr
&=0.
}
 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can treat every term independently and

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x\left\lfloor\frac kx\right\rfloor=\lim_{x\to0^+}x\left(\frac kx-\left\{\frac kx\right\}\right)=k-\lim_{x\to0^+}x\left\{\frac kx\right\}=k,$$ because the fractional part lies in $[0,1)$.

By a similar reasoning,

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\left\lfloor\frac kx\right\rfloor=0.$$